# div not moving when onclick is triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you tell me why my JS ain't working?

http://prime.programming-designs.com/designs/map/

It's suppose to move the mark div to the mouse xy when I click in the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your console, and you'll see:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MouseX' of undefined

It appears that on `line 33` in your javascript code, `document.Show` is `undefined`.

```
document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX;
```

And when you `click`, you get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

around `line 52` where `mark` is `null`:

```
<div id="map" onclick="

mark.style.left = tempX + 'px';
mark.style.top  = tempY + 'px';

">
    <div id="mark"></div>
```

You can move the entire `<script>` tag down toward the bottom, placing it just inside the closing `</body>` tag so that your `document.getElementById('mark');` will find the element.

Like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="map" onclick="

    mark.style.left = tempX + 'px';
    mark.style.top  = tempY + 'px';

    ">
        <div id="mark"></div>            
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var IE = document.all?true:false;
        if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
        document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

        var mark = document.getElementById('mark');

        var tempX = 0;
        var tempY = 0;
        function getMouseXY(e) {
            if (IE) { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
                tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
                tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
            }
            else {  // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
                tempX = e.pageX;
                tempY = e.pageY;
            }  
            if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0;}
            if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0;}

            document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX;
            document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY;
            return true;
        }
    //-->
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: How do I open the console in firefox? Also, how can I fix these problems? I'm a beginner in JS.

Comment: @CyanPrime: In Firefox, you need to download an extension called Firebug. Then you can click the bug icon at the bottom of the window, and you'll be presented with a series of panels across the bottom. In the meantime, I just updated my answer. Move your `<script>` tag toward the bottom of the page. It needs to run *after* the `"mark"` element has successfully loaded.

Comment: Tools > Error Console also works for non-Firebug users in FF.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I use Chrome more often, so I'm as familiar with FF.